# How to setup home network from Broadband to Wireless, Printer, Webserver, Email server and multple PC's

Tags: security, router, dmz

I need to setup a secure home network from a Broadband Modem input to a wireless and LAN to support a webserver, email server, Printer, multiple PC's.
I use DRC Shields Up to test my network is stealthy currently but I don't know If my Broadband Modem and router is able to add an email server and webserver so I can look at faster Broadband which doesn't support webspace and emails like my current ISP.
Should the servers be on one PC running in the DMZ or behind the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

DMZ is more secure but there are many pluses/minuses

Comment: I use the DMZ currently with no PC on tht IP so I am fully stealthed behind my router. But I need to have a web and email server to recieve emails and ahve my own website space so should I place my email and webserver in the DMZ or should it stay behind the NAT firewall?